# display email in web sended via SMTP

Tags: perl, smtp

I have some daemon who send email on request using SMTP and socks proxy. Gmail and hotmail displaying this email in web, but all other(about 10 tested by me) services not display. How i can put email sended via SMTP to "sent" folder?

Comment: This isn't an `perl` question. This is how the SMTP works for **any** SMTP-[MUA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_transfer_agent). You should read at least some [introduction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_transfer_agent) how the mail works.

Comment: My question was asked in order to get an answer as it can be implemented on `perl`. I know how works  MUA, thx.

Answer (score 1):

SMTP only relays emails. SMTP does not save a copy of the sent message into the IMAP "Sent" folder. You will have to copy the message to the IMAP folder programmatically if the service does not save the message when sending a message using SMTP only.

Comment: I thought about what to do so, but it is not a good solution (a new connection imap and the user can use smtp and pop3, and I will not have settings for imap.